# Why do mentions in comment count towards the minimum comment length limit (15)?

Tags: bug, comments, comment-replies

When you write comments, and you want to write to a specific user, you type:

```
@[username] [message]
```

But the `[username]` characters count as those 15, which means you can write a message like:

```
@VeryLongUserName
```

with only a space after, which I think should be invalid.

Comment: @MartijnPieters

Comment: Like the above one

Comment: @MartijnPieters Seems edits not clashed

Answer (score 5):

Is this actually more of a problem than comments like this?

> No. [15 chars.]
>   Yes. [fill 15.]

I don't think so.

Not counting the ping will just create more spacefillers in comments.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It's already easy enough to put a bit of placeholder text in the comment to reach 15 characters. Making the ping (@someone) not count towards it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: But then the reciever would see that as empty but something in their notification bar?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you're talking about now. Would you like to clarify the intent of this suggestion?

Comment: @Scimonster It counts towards it

Answer (score 5):

I don't see this as a bug. I also don't think it is a problem.

There is no difference in using `@LongUserName` and `LongUserName` inside of a comment when considering the amount of characters (aside from being off by 1). The only difference when using the @ is that it causes a "ping" or "notification".

Creating a comment which is little more than a ping to another user and a white space will be removed with flags. Users should know better than to do this because it is slightly rude to the user being notified.

If a user is doing this, flag their comment as "no longer needed". If they continue to do it, a moderator will probably issue a warning to them. If another user is doing this repeatedly to you, then flag their comment as "other" and type in a message explaining the situation.